# Why doesn't the number of commits for a project match the sum of commits from contributors?

Tags: github, git-commit

[This project](https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces) shows 1993 commits, but clicking on Contributors shows a total less than half of that, only 925 total.

Why the discrepancy? Each branch has over 1800 commits.

[image: TagSpaces on GitHub]

Answer (score 2):

The [Repository Graphs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/) help page mentions:

> The Contributors graph shows commits made by the top 100 contributors over the lifetime of your project.
>   **This graph doesn't include merge commits or commits with zero changes**.

If there are many PR for this project, that could explain the delta (or part of it anyway)